# SQLAlchemy not converting column with __ character correctly

Tags: sqlalchemy

I am trying to query a bigquery dataset with SQLAlchemy in a web application written with Django. The table name is TestBillingAcctLkp and it has a particular column `__of_projects` (two underscores in front)

I have defined the model object like this:

```
class TestBillingAcctLkp(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'TestBillingAcctLkp'
    Billing_account_name = Column(String)
    Billing_account_ID = Column(String,primary_key=True)
    Parent_account_ID=Column(String)
    Status=Column(String)
    __of_projects=Column(Integer)
```

In the **views**, I use this:

```
session.query(TestBillingAcctLkp).order_by(text("Billing_account_name asc")).all()
```

When I query I get the SQL like this:

```
 SELECT `TestBillingAcctLkp`.`Billing_account_name` AS `TestBillingAcctLkp_Billing_account_name`, `TestBillingAcctLkp`.`Billing_account_ID` AS `TestBillingAcctLkp_Billing_account_ID`, `TestBillingAcctLkp`.`Parent_account_ID` AS `TestBillingAcctLkp_Parent_account_ID`, `TestBillingAcctLkp`.`Status` AS `TestBillingAcctLkp_Status`, `TestBillingAcctLkp`.`_TestBillingAcctLkp__of_projects` AS `TestBillingAcctLkp__TestBillingAcctLkp__of_projects` FROM `TestBillingAcctLkp` ORDER BY Billing_account_name asc
```

I observe that _TestBillingAcctLkp is getting appended to the front of this column `__of_projects` and it becomes `_TestBillingAcctLkp__of_projects` in the SQL query translation therefore I get this error:

> Exception : (google.cloud.bigquery.dbapi.exceptions.DatabaseError) 400 Name _TestBillingAcctLkp__of_projects not found inside TestBillingAcctLkp at

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Python will combine class variables with two leading underscores with the class name - this is known as [name mangling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html?highlight=mangling#private-variablesl).

If the column in the database has two leading underscores you can specify it in the [column definition](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.__init__), and assign the class variable to a name without leading underscores.

```
class TestBillingAcctLkp(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'TestBillingAcctLkp'
    ...
    of_projects=Column('__of_projects', Integer)
```